# Rotate player with platform without parenting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm currently making a small platformer 3D game, but unfortunately I can't make the player to rotate properly when it is riding the platform, the thing here is that I don't want to make the player child of the platform, so far I've managed to make him move smoothly along with the platform, but the rotation is still going nowhere, here is the code I'm using for the rotation:

```
player.transform.rotation *= platform.rotation;
```

and here is the effect I got:
[Rotation Error](https://youtu.be/kbj4hEGQe74)
not very nice :(
I guess the solution is something simple, some formula, but unfortunately I'm not very good with math :( So, thank you guys, I hope you can help me.

Comment: do you want the player's rotation to be the-same as the platform's  rotation?

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you a simple script example which makes a cube rotate by input while reacting to the rotation of the platform on which it stands:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeRotation : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Platform;
    Quaternion PreviousPlatformRotation;
    public float rotationSpeed = 50;

    private void Start() {
        PreviousPlatformRotation = Platform.transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update() {
        //Rotate the cube by input
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        }

        //Adjust rotation due to platform rotating
        if (Platform.transform.rotation != PreviousPlatformRotation) {
            var platformRotatedBy = Platform.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(PreviousPlatformRotation);
            transform.rotation *= platformRotatedBy;
            PreviousPlatformRotation = Platform.transform.rotation;
        }
    }
}
```

The logic of the adjustment to the platform rotation is this:

1. Get at start the `rotation` quaternion of the platform (in your case, get it when the cube object climbs on the platform)
2. With `A` and `D` rotate the cube normally around the local Y axis.
3. Afterwards check if the platform's `rotation` has changed, if yes:

   3.a Get how much the platform rotated since the previous frame, with the operation `Actual rotation * Inverse(Previous Rotation)`; this operation it's akin to a difference between two quaternions

   3.b Add that quaternion to the cube's `rotation` with the `*=` operator

   3.c Set the platform's previous rotation value to the new one.

That's pretty much it.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but unfortunately I don't know why it doesn't work at all. When I jump on the platform nothing happens, here is the code according to what you wrote:
`void LateUpdate()
{
        _player.transform.position = transform.position + _movOffset;
        if (transform.rotation != PreviousPlatformRotation)
        {
            PreviousPlatformRotation = transform.rotation;
            platformRotatedBy = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(PreviousPlatformRotation);
            _player.transform.rotation *= platformRotatedBy;
        }
} `

Comment: 1) Don't update the rotation in `LateUpdate`, but in `Update` - if you do this the rotation will be updated with a one frame delay; 2) you're executing `PreviousPlatformRotation = transform.rotation;` BEFORE the "subtraction" of the quaternions, this means that there's no difference between the previous and the actual rotation, so the cube doesn't rotate with the platform. Use my code in the same order I posted it.

Comment: Strange, I did what you said, but now when I jump on the platform the camera start to shake left and right and again the player is not rotating, just shaking, here is the order of the code lines:
'if (transform.rotation != PreviousPlatformRotation)
         {
                platformRotatedBy = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(PreviousPlatformRotation);
                _player.transform.rotation *= platformRotatedBy;
                PreviousPlatformRotation = transform.rotation;
         }'

Comment: Are you using the `FPSController` standard asset?

Comment: Yes, it is Unity First Person Character Controller

Comment: Then you need to modify somewhat the code that manages the camera. Namely, passing `platformRotatedBy` to the `LookRotation()` of  `MouseLook.cs` when it's called by `RotateView()` of `FirstPersonController.cs`. You may need to extend the arguments of `LookRotation()` adding a `Quaternion` type.